# Refresh data in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a program which calculates an integer and then uses the value within a JLabel. On intital creation everything is fine with the initialized value, but when I change the value of the int within the label I can't seem to find a way to update the JLabel. The relevant code is as follows:

```
    JLabel carbLbl;
    int totCarbs = 0;

    public Main() {
        carbLbl = new JLabel("Total Carbs: " + totCarbs);
        carbLbl.setFont(new Font("KidSans", Font.PLAIN, 38));
        carbLbl.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

    void addFoodToTable() {
        String[] s = new String[3];
        s = (String[]) foodData.get(foodChoice.getSelectedIndex());
        foodList.addRow(s);
        totCarbs += Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
        carbLbl.repaint();
    }
}
```

There's obviously much more code, but it's too long to include the entire script. Is there a way I can have the label update whenever I invoke the `addFoodToTable()` method?

Comment: Where are you setting the text for the JLabel? You know: `carbLbl.setText(String.valueOf(totCarbs));`. You also can't have a method (addFoodToTable) within a method (main).

Comment: The text is originally set within the constructor. Also, addFoodToTable() isn't within Main, I just pasted snippits for clarity sake.

Answer (score 1):

The `JLabel` is not "bound" to your integer variable. When you change the integer you need to update the `JLabel` using `carbLbl.setText(String.valueOf(totCarbs))`

Comment: Which is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. But if I reset the text I can't include the integer. I tried carbLbl.setText("Total Carbs" + totCarbs); but it wouldn't accept it.

Comment: Now you're into basic programming. Search for "concatenate int string java". What do you mean "wouldn't accept it"

Comment: I understand the concept of concatenation, but I just feel like that's a workaround. Is there not a way to simply update the JLabel using the initial constructor parameters?

Comment: Not simply - search for "data binding swing" and you may get some advice - in short you'll be writing your own framework or picking one someone may have already written...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there not a way to simply update the JLabel using the initial constructor parameters?

```
carbLbl = new JLabel("Total Carbs: " + totCarbs);
```

What parameters? There is only a single parameter, the String to be displayed.

The compiler concatenates the hard coded String with the value of your "totCarbs" variable to create a single String.

The compiler will essentially treat the above code like:

```
String text = "Total Carbs" + totCarbs;
carbLbl = new JLabel( text );
```

The JLabel has no idea how the String was created (ie. that a variable was used to build the string).

> I understand the concept of concatenation, but I just feel like that's a workaround

It is not a work around. The API of the setText(...) method states you provide a single String. So, if you want to update the label you need to provide the entire String.